# Overring menu blocks in Django DTL?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I got a navbar that will have four links,

```
{% block navbar %}    
<div id="navbar">
  <a href="">Link 1</a>
  <a href="">Link 2</a>
  <a href="">Link 3</a>
  <a href="">Link 4</a>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

A class='current' will define the current active page like

```
<a href="" class='current'>Link 4</a>
```

My question, is overriding the block navbar on each of the 4 links the best way to do it in Django template language so that each link will have a corresponding class 'current'?

Comment: it appears that overriding the block navbar on each of the 4 links the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to solve this, the right one depends on your exact project. This being said, the simplest solution that could possibly work is to use the `{% with %}` tag and `{{ block.super }}`, ie:

In your base template:

```
{% block navbar %}    
<div id="navbar">
  <a href="" class="{% if current == "link1" %}current{% endif %}">Link 1</a>
  <a href="" class="{% if current == "link2" %}current{% endif %}">Link 2</a>
  <a href="" class="{% if current == "link3" %}current{% endif %}">Link 3</a>
  <a href="" class="{% if current == "link4" %}current{% endif %}">Link 4</a>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

And then in the template for the "Link1" page:

```
{% block navbar %}
  {% with current="link1" %}
    {{ block.super }}
  {% endwith %}
{% endblock %}
```

etc...

Comment: well this is pretty much the same as hard coding the links, just a bit more indirect but hard coded string literals still rule the day

Comment: This is totally different actually - you can change the urls without having to change the templates.

Comment: well, that point certainly is correct. However I am yet to be convinced because you are now doing more work in both the base template as well as the derived template.

Comment: I assume you hardcode your urls too instead of using the `{% url %}` tag then ? Because it's more work to use the `{% url %}` tag - and actually totally useless as soon as you have even a single hardcoded url somewhere in your code base...

Comment: where does the {% url %} tag  come into this discussion?

Comment: Quite simply: the goal of the `{% url %}` tag (and it's Python version `urlresolvers.reverse()`) is to avoid hardcoding urls in your code, so the `urls` definitions are handled in a single point (the `urls.py` files). As soon as you hardcode an url anywhere in your code, you totally defeat this feature, and any url change implies chasing urls through the whole code base. Been here, done that, and I definitly prefer a couple more lines in my templates to make sure I'll never have to do it again - but YMMV ;)

Comment: I am aware of the use of url resolvers but I am still struggling to fathom how it pictures in your answer. But never mind :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131787/discussion-between-bruno-desthuilliers-and-e4c5).

Comment: what about this : `<a href="{% url myapp:page1 %}" class={% if request.path == '/link1/' %}current{% endif %}">Link 1</a>` ? What's the point of using the `{% url %}` tag here since as soon as you change the url for `myapp:page1` you break the test on request.path ? Also, if using i18n_urls + translated urls, the test on `request.path` becomes very complicated and requires even more hardcoding (and updates each time a translation changes or a language is added).